# Reuse Core Data entities

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch, core-data

I noticed that I am recreating a number of entities in different `Core Data` Apps over and over.

Is there any way to reuse entities in different data models? Something like a library of frequently used entities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, because your `NSManagedObjectModel` instance can be composed from more than one model file. The easiest way to do this is probably:

1. Create multiple model files in your app project. One can be a collection of shared entities that gets used in multiple projects.
2. At run time, create an `NSManagedObjectModel` for each of the files, using `initWithContentsOfURL:`.
3. Combine all the instances from step 2 into a single unified model using `modelByMergingModels:` That will give you a new `NSManagedObjectModel` instance with all of the entities from each all of the model files.

Use the model from step 3 in your Core Data stack.

It's also possible to combine models using `mergedModelFromBundles:`, which will seek out all existing models in the specified bundles (the app bundle, or framework bundles). I prefer to be explicit about the models I'm loading, but either approach works.